# In tensorflow, how can I make py_func return Matrix

Tags: types, tensorflow

I wanna make my tf model train same labeled MNIST data
simply say just i want training one-number MNIST
anyway It is not important, I need how can I make py_func return Matrix

```
def redefine(number):
    pixel, label = MNIST('./mnist/data/').load_training()
    index = 0
    result = list()
    for num in label:
        if num == number:
            result.append(pixel[index])
        index =+ 1
    return result
```

this is my function code and

```
number = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
tf_redefine = tf.py_func(redefine, [number], ???)
```

this is my additional code for converting to adaptable value for tensorflow
everything is OK but I don't know what I have to fill at '???'
because It was not work filling as

```
tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32,size=2)
```

please, help me guys...
Thank you!

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same issue as I want to load data and do some kind of `flatMap()` operation.

Comment: @Vince.Bdn sorry, finally I didn't use 'redefine' method but I just realized that I have to write 'Tensor' not 'TensorArray' in '???' ... sorry to helpless